# How to implement a generic function in Rust which performs dynamic dispatch?

Tags: generics, rust, dynamic-dispatch

In a project I am working on there is this object:

```
enum ContainedType {
    SomeType,
    OtherType,
    ...
}
struct OurObject {
    contains: ContainedType,
    ...
}

impl OurObject {
    pub fn unpack_sometype(self) -> AType { ... }
    pub fn unpack_othertype(self) -> BType { ... }
    ...
}
```

`OurObject` is a container of things that are 'packed' in some way.
Each thing that can be packed implements various traits.

We end with repeated code like:

```
match foo.type() {
    SomeType => action(foo.unpack_sometype()),
    OtherType => action(foo.unpack_othertype()),
    ...
}
```

I would like to factor out the `match` code into a function so we can dispatch on an arbitrary trait.

```
action(foo)
```

However, I run into problems...

```
pub fn dispatch<T>(obj: OurObject) -> Box<T> {
    match obj.type() {
        SomeType => Box::new(obj.unpack_sometype()),
        OtherType => Box::new(obj.unpack_othertype()),
        ...
    }
}
```

`T` here is supposed to stand-in for an arbitrary trait like `Debug` or `SomeLocalTrait`.

I have also tried using turbofish like `Box::<T>::new()` but to no avail. The compiler complains that `T` does not tell the compiler it is only a trait. There is `?Sized` but I cannot find a `?IAmTrait`. The new Rust 2018 `impl Trait` syntax fails in similar ways.

I have worked around this for now by creating functions with a macro. So I have `dispatch_debug` or `dispatch_cool_trait`. Essentially re-implementing the generics interface. Since we want to use this for unrelated traits I cannot use some form of parent trait. `Debug` or `Display` is not related to any trait we would create.

Is there a better way? In a perfect world we would have a `dispatch` function or method which would allow us to say:

```
action(foo.dispatch<SomeTrait>())
```

This is a sandbox showing a simplified version to start the conversation.
https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=7b739ab11da15ec793ee46c2d8ac47fc

Comment: Your example is missing a lot of useful information. You can't actually match against a *type*, in the Rust sense, so what does `foo.type()` do? What trait or traits do `foo.unpack_sometype()` and `foo.unpack_othertype()` have in common that it's possible for either of them to be passed to `action`? Please create a [mcve] if it is at all possible.

Comment: Not sure, but do you really need `Box<T>`? Wouldn't a `&T` (trait object reference) suffice? Moreover, I guess that `dispatch` requires that both `SomeType` and `OtherType` implement the trait `T`.

Comment: The Traits are not relevant. I am asking if there is a way to dispatch to an arbitrary Trait.

Comment: @phimuemue I do not know either. I documented what I have tried.

Comment: Let's see if I can sum this up: You have some type representing packed information with a type tag, e.g. a network packet representation. Depending on the tag, the type can unpack into one of a number of different types. All of those types implement a number of traits. Finally, you want to call various functions that expect trait objects of those traits, by unpacking the struct into the correct type and calling the function with the resulting object. Correct?

Comment: That would be an excellent start @SebastianRedl. I can work out more from there. Your summary is solid.

Comment: What is the purpose of the `Box` in your attempted solution? If the idea is dynamic dispatch, `T` should be a trait not a type variable.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out where I am not being clear. I was too deep in it to see where I was not being more explicit @PeterHall.

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to move away from enumerations, you can use additional traits to dispatch with:

```
trait ObjectTrait {
    fn example1(&self);
    fn example2(&self);
}

struct Object2<E> {
    thing: E,
}

impl<E: fmt::Debug + MeaninglessNumeric> ObjectTrait for Object2<E> {
    fn example1(&self) {
        println!("{:?}", self.thing);
    }
    fn example2(&self) {
        println!("{}", self.thing.numeric());
    }
}

fn example3(o: &ObjectTrait) {
    o.example1();
}
fn example4(o: &ObjectTrait) {
    o.example2();
}
```

After that you can adjust your main:

```
fn main() {
    let obj1 = OurObject {
        contains: ContainedType::SomeType,
    };
    let obj2 = OurObject {
        contains: ContainedType::OtherType,
    };
    let obj3 = Object2 {
        thing: AType { value: 5 },
    };
    let obj4 = Object2 {
        thing: BType {
            contents: "Hello, World".to_string(),
        },
    };

    example1(obj1);
    example2(obj2);
    example3(&obj3);
    example4(&obj4);
}
```

[Full playground example](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=88901625764571ff0d69258284ffc78a)

Comment: The issue here is that becomes a LONG list of `A + B + C ....` in the where clause of anything that implements `ObjectTrait`.

Comment: You'd have to show an example.  I was more envisioning providing different sets of traits for Object2 to implement.  ObjectTrait was just one set.  The idea would not be to put them all together, just the ones that by design go together.  So not A + B + C but One set Of A + B, one of A + C, maybe just B for some.  If you are dispatching you have to have some bounds on what can dispatch.

Comment: for example, you might add another trait ObjectTrait2 { fn example3(&self)} and then implement it:  impl<E: Deref> ObjectTrait2 for Object2<E>{ ...stuff...} then you can dispatch on that for types that implement Deref